# Change sidetap nav to appear on the right side

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using sidetap [(click here to find the jquery plugin)](http://sidetap.it). I've gotten it to work, however I wanted to make the nav appear on the right, not on the left which is the default.

Here is the skeleton I used

```
    <div class="sidetap">
        <div class="stp-nav" id="notification-sidebar">
          <div>
            <nav>
              <a href="#" class="selected">Selected Nav Item</a>
              <a href="#">Second Nav Item</a>
              <a href="#">Third Nav Item</a>
              <a href="#">Fourth Nav Item</a>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="stp-content" id="content">
            <!-- content goes here -->
        </div>

    </div>
```

And below is the jquery I used:

```
    // Initialize Sidetap for notification
    var st = sidetap();
    $("#navigation-btn").on("click", st.toggle_nav);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
.sidetap {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Wish it was that simple @Adsy, just added this piece of code `
                        st.show_section('#notification-sidebar', {
                            animation: 'infromright'
                        });`
                        and now I have the nav inner background sliding in from the right

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?